# Restrict access to a page if not logging in with Firebase Authentification + retrieve data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a login page with the following code (taken from firebase sample auth app):

```
    function initApp() {
  // Listening for auth state changes.
  // [START authstatelistener]
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').disabled = true;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    if (user) {
        window.location = 'index.html';
      // User is signed in.
      var displayName = user.displayName;
      var email = user.email;
      var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      var photoURL = user.photoURL;
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      var uid = user.uid;
      var providerData = user.providerData;
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
      document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify(user, null, '  ');
      if (!emailVerified) {
        document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').disabled = false;
      }
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
      document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = 'null';
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
  });
  // [END authstatelistener]
  document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').addEventListener('click', toggleSignIn, false);
  document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-up').addEventListener('click', handleSignUp, false);
  document.getElementById('quickstart-verify-email').addEventListener('click', sendEmailVerification, false);
  document.getElementById('quickstart-password-reset').addEventListener('click', sendPasswordReset, false);
}
window.onload = function() {
  initApp();
};
```

I just added the line `window.location = 'index.html'`, in order to redirect the user to index.html when logging in.

Now on my index.html file, I have the following JS code:

```
     function initApp() {

          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

            if (user) {

      // User is signed in.
      var displayName = user.displayName;
      var email = user.email;
      var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
      var photoURL = user.photoURL;
      var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
      var uid = user.uid;
      //var uid = bCbADd1qJqhoVbDg0QCDIlq5eMx1;
      var providerData = user.providerData;
      }
     else {
     window.location = 'login.html';
    }
  });
}
window.onload = function() {
  initApp();
};


window.onload = function() {      
document.getElementById('sign-out').onclick = function toggleSignOut() {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
    window.location = 'login.html';
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});
}
}

   var database = firebase.database();
    database.ref(`user_profiles/${uid}/name`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var username = photosSnap.val();
    $('#username').html(username);    
    });
```

There is a sign-out button that works. My issue is that this page should only be accessible by someone logged in, but with the present code anyone can access it, logged in or not. I thought this part would make it:

`else { 
window.location = 'login.html';`

What shall I implement to restrict access?

Moreover, I would like to retrieve userid from the current logged in user. The last part of the above code should make it, but it doesn't retrieve anything. I'm using uid variable, which is set above by var uid = user.uid;

Comment: What are you attempting to restrict access to? Surely not the HTML itself. If it's data retrieved from your Firebase Database, you restrict that at the DB level using [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: I would like the user to be redirected to login.html if he is not logged in